# Java prevent string escaping with marshaller

Tags: java, marshalling

I have an object in java with string, I need to convert it in XML. For that, I'm using JAXBMarshaller.

The problem is when using `marshaller.marshal(object, sw);`, special characters are escaped, for example a quote `"` become `&quot;`

```
<example>This is a &quot;Test&quot; &lt;></example>
```

Is there a way to prevent that ?

Note : I can impact the object, xml and xsd, but not the marshal mechanism (creation of JAXBContext and Marshaller).

Comment: Not escaping these characters represents a security risk.

Comment: These characters are supposed to be escaped. Why do you not want them to be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

To handle escape characters during the XML conversion, you have to configure the marshaller instances as below

```
     marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode"); 
     marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
     marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new CustomCharacterEscapeHandler());
```

`CustomCharacterEscapeHandler` implementation

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class CustomCharacterEscapeHandler implements CharacterEscapeHandler {

    public CustomCharacterEscapeHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, Writer out) throws IOException {
        // avoid calling the Writerwrite method too much by assuming
        // that the escaping occurs rarely.
        // profiling revealed that this is faster than the naive code.
        int limit = start+length;
        for (int i = start; i < limit; i++) {
            char c = ch[i];
            if(c == '&' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '\'' || (c == '\"' && isAttVal) ) {
                if(i!=start)
                    out.write(ch,start,i-start);
                start = i+1;
                switch (ch[i]) {
                    case '&':
                        out.write("&amp;");
                        break;
                    case '<':
                        out.write("&lt;");
                        break;
                    case '>':
                        out.write("&gt;");
                        break;
                    case '\"':
                        out.write("&quot;");
                        break;
                    case '\'':
                        out.write("&apos;");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if( start!=limit )
            out.write(ch,start,limit-start);
    }
}
```

`jaxb-core` dependency contains the `CharacterEscapeHandler` class